# not passing state correctly in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am trying to toggle a modal from separate components. the first most common component is my app.tsx so i set the state in that file.

```
type TokenUpdateType = {

sessionToken: string | undefined | null, 
createActive: boolean
}


export default class App extends Component<{}, TokenUpdateType> {

constructor(props: TokenUpdateType) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

        sessionToken: undefined,

        createActive: false

    }
...

toggleModal = () => {
this.setState({createActive: !this.state.createActive})
}

return 

<Home isOpen={this.state.createActive} toggleModal={this.toggleModal} />
```

my home component takes these props and passes again to another component

```
type AuthProps = {

isOpen: boolean

toggleModal: () => void

...

}

const Home = (props: AuthProps) => {

return(

    <>

        <Sidebar sessionToken={props.sessionToken} toggleModal={props.toggleModal}

        <ChannelEntryModalDisplay  sessionToken={props.sessionToken} isOpen={props.isOpen} toggleModal={props.toggleModal}/>

    </>

)
```

}

isOpen gets passes to my modal component and is used in this component

```
type AuthProps = {

isOpen: boolean

toggleModal: () => void

...

}

const ChannelEntryModalDisplay = (props: AuthProps) => {

return(

    <div>

        <Modal show={props.isOpen}>

        <ChannelEntry sessionToken={props.sessionToken}/>

        <Button className='button' type='button' outline onClick={props.toggleModal}>close</Button>

        </Modal>

    </div>

)

}
```

my modal is not showing even when i set createactive to true. i believe i may be passing props incorrectly but im not sure what i am doing incorrectly. i appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Hi @Irvin Lee, looks like props are getting passed appropriately , could you debug the value of isOpen prop in ChannelEntryModalDisplay  component?
May I know which UI library you are using?

Comment: hello @PriyankaPanjabi, thank you for commenting! The value of isOpen is false in ChannelEntryModalDisplay in the inspect page and i believe i am using reactstrap for my modal.

Comment: @PriyankaPanjabi Also i noticed that when I set createActive to true the value of isOpen is true when passed to home but false when passed to the Modal component

Comment: @PriyankaPanjabi AHHH i got it xD. instead of show the correct syntax for reactstrap modal is isOpen XDD. thanks alot though i would have never gotten it if you hadnt made me work my brain.

Answer (score -1):

try to create a new state from the props:

```
const [createActive, setCreateActive] = useState<boolean>()

constructor(props: TokenUpdateType)
{
    super(props)
    setCreateActive(props.createActive)
}

useEffect(() => {
    setCreateActive(props.createActive) // update the state when props changes
}, [props])

...
toggleModal = () => {
    this.setCreateActive(!createActive)
}

<Home isOpen={createActive} toggleModal={this.toggleModal} />
```

Comment: Is this. functional component or a class component? If it is a class component, you should use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). Also take a look at[You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)